# Where can I find the F# runtime for Silverlight 4

Tags: silverlight, f#, silverlight-4.0

I have been playing around with Silverlight & F# and tried to make a Silverlight 4 application in VS2010 Professional.

When I try and compile my application I get the following error message...

*Error 12   F# runtime for Silverlight version v4.0 is not installed. Please go to http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=177463 to download and install matching..*

For the life of me I cannot find the runtime on this page or a place to download it. Does anyone know of the actual URL

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not available yet.

"F# Runtime for Silverlight 4" will be included with the RTM release of the "Silverlight 4 Tools for Visual Studio 2010".  I'm not sure exactly when that comes out; sometime in the next month I think maybe.

(In the meantime, you can use Silverlight 3.)

Answer (score 3):

You can try making one for Silverlight 3, then referencing that from the Silverlight 4 Project.

I know it will let you do that in Visual Studio, Edit: Confirmed to work for a basic function (shown below). However library support will likely be bad (or spotty) due to conflicting versions, but as a stand alone library it should do ok.

```
module Module1
    let testfunction value =
        value + 1
```

Answer (score 1):

I come along 2 years later and try to do this same thing, but see that the provided link still won't setup the F# runtime for me.  I came across this post, [Installing F# for Silverlight 4 runtime in VS2010 with SP1](http://nmorais.wordpress.com/2011/11/08/installing-f-for-silverlight-4-runtime-in-vs2010-with-sp1/), which solved the issue for me.

Relevant detail from the page:

> 1. Download the Microsoft Silverlight 4 Tools for Visual Studio 2010
> 2. Don’t execute the installer (these tools are already installed by the VS2010 SP1 – but not all of them – see Description of Visual
>      Studio 2010 Service Pack 1 and Microsoft Silverlight 4 Tools for
>      Visual Studio 2010 and compare the differences)
> 3. Extract the files from the installer and look for the file FSharpRuntimeSL4.msi
> 4. Install the FSharpRuntimeSL4.msi
>
> To validate the installation you can check if the C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Microsoft F#\Silverlight\Libraries\Client\v4.0 folder was
>   created or see the you have the Microsoft F# Runtime for Silverlight 4
>   version 2.0.0.0 on the list of programs installed.